# How to get result from subsciber as function's return value?

Tags: angular

I want to set boolean value of canActivate function based on the result that I get inside subscribeer method. However this gives me an error saying: `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.` I am unable  to identify exactly what is wrong with my code and how can I modify it to work?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProblemAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.apiService.canEdit(route.params['id'])
      .subscribe(obj => {
        if (obj['result'] === 'public') {
          this.router.navigate(['403']);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Here is the implementation of `canEdit` method from `apiService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';


const apiUrl = environment.apiURL;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  canEdit(problemId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl + '/archive/problems/' + problemId + '/visibility');
  }

}
```

Comment: try to console any value withing ` obj=>{}`

Comment: and try removing `: Observable<any> ` from the apiservice function

Comment: @Exterminator I am able to successfully console the value of obj['result'] inside the subscriber. My problem is not being able to determine the return value of canActivate function based on the comparision inside subsriber method.

Comment: add the `console.log(obj)` data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.apiService.canEdit(route.params['id'])
      .subscribe(obj => {
        if (obj['result'] === 'public') {
          this.router.navigate(['403']);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
  }
```

Here you're not really returning anything, and you said your method will return boolean.

`return false` and `return true` return to your subscribe function, not `canActivate` function.

But since you're fetching your data asynchronously, you can't return boolean at all, you will have to return Observable still.

Change your code to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.apiService.canEdit(route.params['id'])
      .pipe(map(obj => {
        if (obj['result'] === 'public') {
          this.router.navigate(['403']);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }));
  }
```

That way you can return Observable of your boolean to your guard (guards can receive `boolean`, `Observable<boolean>` and `Promise<boolean>`).